# Not able to make work the reduce files selection from an input working, updating the whole first selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

I have an API in Django where on one page the user can uplaod files. I am using this HTML code:

I want that after the selection the files are displayed and that the user can remove the files that he wants before uploading. To do it, I help me from what I could find on internet, I try to use this jQuery code that works to display and remove the files from the list on the webpage. However when I submit, it uploads the first selection with the files that were removed.

```js
function updateList() {
  var input = document.getElementById('id_Filename');
  var list = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = input.files.length; i < len; ++i) {
    list.push(input.files.item(i));
  }
  outputList(list);
}

function outputList(list) {
  var output = document.getElementById('fileselect');
  while (output.hasChildNodes()) {
    output.removeChild(output.lastChild);
  }

  var nodes = document.createElement('ul');
  for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; ++i)(function(i) {
    var node = document.createElement('li');
    var filename = document.createTextNode(list[i].name);
    var removeLink = document.createElement('a');

    removeLink.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
    removeLink.innerHTML = 'Remove';
    removeLink.onclick = function() {
      list.splice(i, 1); // remove item
      outputList(list);
    }

    node.appendChild(filename);
    node.appendChild(removeLink);
    nodes.appendChild(node);
  })(i);

  output.appendChild(nodes);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" name="Filename" class="form-control" multiple="" onchange="javascript:updateList()" maxlength="255" id="id_Filename">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitupload">Charger
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-upload" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M.5 9.9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2.5a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v2.5a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"></path>
                        <path d="M7.646 1.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8.5 2.707V11.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V2.707L5.354 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708l3-3z"></path>
                      </svg>
                </button>

<div class="block-file-selection">
                <p>
                    Selected files :
                </p>

                <div id="fileselect">
                </div>
            </div>
```

What is wrong or what is missing ?

Thank you

Comment: Even though you are displaying the files correctly the input[type="file"] still has the original files list as its value. You have to manually send the request from js because you cannot change the file inputs value.

Comment: @CodeSpirit Thank you, What do you mean by send the request by JS. Do you have a code to share aor a link in example ?

Comment: You can submit it using `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`. Heres an example https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Ajax-JavaScript-file-upload-example